# DEA mode activation in Dymola

Tags: solver, dymola

I have a problem regarding solving the model in DAE mode. I need to know the procedure for the activation of the DAE flag in Dymola 2019.

Answer (score 1):

That is described in the release notes:

> 3.3 Simulating a model
>
> 3.3.1 DAE Mode
>   Dymola 2019 supports DAE (Differential-Algebraic Equations) mode. DAE mode is activated by setting the flag
>
> ```
> Advanced.Define.DAEsolver = true
> ```
>
> DAE mode is supported by the integrators Dassl, Radau IIa, Esdirk23a,
>   Esdirk34a, Esdirk45a, and Sdirk34hw. (The flag is by default false.)

Note that there has been improvements in the mode for Dymola 2020 and that not all models benefit from DAE-mode.

See also the conference paper: https://modelica.org/events/modelica2019/proceedings/html/papers/Modelica2019paper4D1.pdf

Comment: Is this DAE mode gonna cause an initialization failure in some cases?

Comment: At least with Dymola 2020 or later it shouldn't cause any new initialization failures as initialization (and events) use the non-DAE variant of the equations. As explained in section 3.3 of the paper there are some issues for event localization - but initialization avoids that.